# ReactJs - Weird behaviour of Data being entered in reversed order

Tags: html, reactjs

I am using Reactjs in an ElectronJS project. There seems to be an intermittent problem where when i type some text in a textbox it types in reverse order (screenshot: https://share.getcloudapp.com/DOuxq0b2).

This happens sometimes (on both windows and macos) when I select a pre-existing entry and start typing over it (without hitting delete first). But doesn’t always happen consistently. I am not sure why this happens and most of the times i am unable to reproduce this. My program simply saves the data that is being entered in a state on the onChange event. I am not even sure if this is bug in Reactjs or html.

I was wondering if any of you have faced this when building projects with react or electronjs, if so how did you fix this?

Comment: Without looking at the code, it will be difficult to help

Comment: Please update question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.